# Custom CocoaPod Framework with Other Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode9.2

There is so many things written about it but still I am unable to figure it out.

So here what I am doing:
I have create a Cocoapod Test Framework with code borrowed from some tutorial here and there. [Repo](https://github.com/thevirus20/CocoaPodTestFramework)

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CocoaPodTestFramework' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

In the framework I needed a http call so I used Alamofire and SwitfyJSON pods in my framework workspace. After successful buidling process I get three framework files:

1. CocoaPodTestFramework.framework
2. Alamofire.framework
3. SwiftyJSON.framework

Now When I want to use it a app and created a few test app to test my framework.

1. Swift: the app is not using cocoapod(normal Xcode Project not workspace), I simply link all the 3 framework and it work.
2. For Objective-C App, I did the same and it worked.
3. Now in the another Swift app which uses Cocoapods I have added following in my Podfile

**Podfile of Sample App**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'Cocoapod Test App' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'CocoaPodTestFramework', :path => '/Users/ABCD/Documents/Projects/TEST/CocoaPodTestFramework'
end
```

Now here the issue comes, whenever I tried to build the app I get 
`no such module 'Alamofire'` in the Referenced framework and in the app it says `no such module 'CocoaPodTestFramework'`

Having been reading various post/forums/issue since then but unable to figure it out how can it be fixed tried adding `pod 'Alamofire'` and `pod 'SwiftyJSON'` in app Podfile as well but still getting the same error.
And also tried adding 'Alamofire' and 'SwiftyJSON' in .podspec (s.frameworks) file of the framework which gives error though.

So I want to know if there is workaround for this or if it is not possible at all?

Read somewhere to use framework project as submodule of the sample app, will this solve the issue?If yes then how can anyone else use this pod if I don't want to share the code I mean without submitting the code only sharing .framework file(Basically Its should like a SDK, source of which I can't share  but need to use other pod :P, Even I would like to skip github part searching a way for that as well)

Can anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 1):

OK...
Here how I have figured it out it may help someone like me...

**Podfile**

```
s.dependency "Alamofire"
s.dependency "SwiftyJSON"
```

The above 2 lines have solved the issue still I don't want to close this thread until I developed the actual SDK to check if this will actually work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran through this problem before , I created a dynamic framework that uses pods to accomplish it's process as a chat module , after dragging it to a project it can't see the sub-frameworks and give the same errors you described, finally i figured out that nested frameworks are not allowed in IOS only MACOS ,seems like framework code must be pure code without sub-frameworks to work , wrote a post in Apple forums and they responded like this

[image]